# Pass flags to NodeJS's Chrome V8 engine in Azure Web Apps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, v8

I have deployed NodeJS application on Azure Web Apps. How to pass flags to NodeJS's Chrome V8 engine?

In my local machine I can do it easily while running the server script as below.

```
node -nouse-idle-notification -expose-gc -max-old-space-size=8192 server.js
```

Where to specify these flags in Azure Web Apps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this either in `iisnode.yml` or in `web.config`. If you are deploying via git, you likely don't have those in your repo. You can get the default generated `web.config` by using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) and finding it under `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. By default, there is no `iisnode.yml` at all.

### Using iisnode.yml

Just put the following line in the `iisnode.yml`:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: node.exe --nouse-idle-notification --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=1024
```

Or if you use a full path to a version of Node, you'll need to quote it, e.g.

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\5.7.1\node.exe" --nouse-idle-notification --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=1024
```

### Using web.config

Toward the end of the file, you'll see a commented out `<iisnode>` tag. Replace it by something like this:

```
<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe --nouse-idle-notification --expose-gc --max-old-space-size=1024"/>
```

### Notes

- `iisnode.yml` takes precedence over `web.config`
- I lowered your `max-old-space-size` value as that was blowing up when I tried, but that's orthogonal.

Then with either file, you can commit them in your repo so it just works on deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I found both `iisnode.yml` and `web.config` files under `d:\home\site\wwwroot`  by default. When I set flags using `iisnode.yml` my application didn't run after deployment. However is no issue with 2nd approach i.e. using `web.config`.

Comment: Make sure you get the double quotes right in the yml case, as in my example. If you quote the whole thing it doesn't work.

Comment: Adding to `iisnode.yml` will let Azure simply not start my application. Adding to `web.config` has no effect in my app. Node still crashes where the memory usage is high.