# Cannot use "max-old-space" parameter in web.config/Azure WebApp

Tags: node.js, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service, iisnode

I have a WebApp running node, i need to increase RAM so i put 
     
in web.config, this works fine.

When i set the max-old-space-size to 2048 the server only answers with

"mything.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500."

I got this [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455380/pass-flags-to-nodejss-chrome-v8-engine-in-azure-web-apps).

Instance Size is a large 'Basic' with 7 GB RAM, azure platform is set to 64GB.
I can use LESS memory, it's working fine when i set memory to 512(MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**B3** is a type in Service Plan, its RAM is shared in all applications in the service plan. And to a single web app instance, it seems up edge value of RAM is 2GB. In my test, `-max-old-space-size=2047` works fine.