# Depreciation warning does not allow deploying an Application on AZURE,

Tags: node.js, azure, sequelize.js, tedious

I get the following warning while deploying my application to AZURE.

> (node:6568) [DEP0064] DeprecationWarning: tls.createSecurePair() is
>   deprecated. Please use tls.Socket instead.

But this does not allow my application to start. Azure logs show the following thing:

[image]

PATH OF LOGS: ***D:\home\LogFiles\Application>***

Comment: what are the contents of the `.txt` file?

Comment: The one I have highlighted.

Comment: This looks to be a warning specifically around Node. Do you have a library that might be using the tls.createSecurePair call? Also, it would be nice to know what was inside the txt file you've highlighted, not just that there is a file there as Shahzeb mentioned.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is some what else.  Because from the console of Azure App, I am able to invoke the service by using the curl command. But outside, its not accessible.  **The highlighted text in the question belongs to the mentioned text file**, but I think its useless now.  App is working, but I am unable to access it from outside azure machine.

Comment: What port is your server trying to listen on? Can you please show the code you're using?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is already 8 month old, but just for completeness I am going to provide the answer on how to suppress warnings for Node in Azure. There is actually multiple ways:

### Using iisnode.yml

Just put the following line in the iisnode.yml:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: node.exe --no-deprecation --no-warnings
```

Or if you use a full path to a version of Node, you'll need to quote it, e.g.

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe" --no-deprecation --no-warnings
```

### Using web.config

Toward the end of the file, you'll see a commented out  tag. Replace it by something like this:

```
<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe --no-deprecation --no-warnings"/>
```

### Notes

iisnode.yml takes precedence over web.config

See the original post on how to add runtime flags in Azure here: [Pass flags to NodeJS's Chrome V8 engine in Azure Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455380/pass-flags-to-nodejss-chrome-v8-engine-in-azure-web-apps)