# Remove 'Bufffer() depreciation' warning in Node JS

Tags: node.js, node-modules, iisnode

I am running a Node project on a Windows server using iisnode, and I get the following iisnode output

> (node:9616) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due
>   to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(),
>   Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

I understand what the message is saying, but I don't use `Buffer()` in any of my code.

I assume that it must be one of my node modules that uses it but [this article from NodeSource](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-buffer-deprecation-in-node-js-10/) seems to suggest that the warning is only thrown *outside* of the `node_modules` folder.

Regardless of whether this article is correct or not, I am getting the warning as an output of iisnode and I've even had it throw an error page at a user so I would like a way to block it/remove the deprecated use. Even if there's a way to identify which node module is causing the problem, that would be helpful.

I am using Node v10.15.1

Comment: `iisnode` itself is known to use `new Buffer()`, which will trigger this warning.  See https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/issues/60 and https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/pull/62 for proposed fixes.  Or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402712/1334967 for a way to silence the warning.

Comment: @ottomeister Ah I see, thank-you very much