# How to globally disable buffer warnings in Node.js

Tags: express, buffer, warnings, global

I am running an Express API with Node.js using `mssql@3.3.0`.

An older version of `mssql` is being used to align with other compatibility issues that we're having.

However, when trying to use promises to chain requests together I am getting the following error:

> DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

How do I disable this warning and run the code in "unsafe" mode using IISNode / Express?

Answer (score 1):

I am using node14, it also shows this warning, I tried Kade's solution, but it does not work, after search the internet, I found the code below works:

```
const warning = process.emitWarning;
process.emitWarning = (...args) => {
    if (args[2] !== 'DEP0005') {
        return warning.apply(process, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and here is how I resolved it.

First, as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380280/depreciation-warning-does-not-allow-deploying-an-application-on-azure/53402712#53402712), I added the following code to my *web.config* file (as a child of *system.webServer*):

```
<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine='"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --no-warnings' />
```

This made it so that **all** warnings were not sent to *stderr*.
I only wanted to suppress the Buffer() Deprecation warning.

[This article](https://medium.com/@jasnell/introducing-process-warnings-in-node-v6-3096700537ee) explains that even though the *no-warnings* flag is used, "the Node.js processes object will also emit the *warning* event". So, I then added the following code to my *server.js* file:

```
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
    if (!warning.message.includes("Buffer() is deprecated")) {
        console.error(warning);
    }
});
```

Now, only the Buffer() Deprecation warning is ignored.