# Query/headers too large on Azure if auth enabled

Tags: node.js, azure, express, iis, iisnode

I have a node/express app that works great locally. I have uploaded it to Azure Web App and it works fine as long as I do not enable authentication. When I enable AAD auth, the app fails with STATUS 500.1011 "Bad Request". I have quite a few query parameters in the url. If I reduce the length of the parameters sufficiently the app load fine again. It seems there is some limit on the query/headers in Azure?

I have tried for several hours now to fix this, but I think I have to admit defeat. I thought maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length) would fix it, but it does not seems like it.

This is my current web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="true" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" maxUrl="65536"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Node reduced max header size from 80kb to 8kb in [November 2018](https://www.nearform.com/blog/protecting-node-js-from-uncontrolled-resource-consumption-headers-attacks/).

There is lots of discussion about it [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24692) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/issues/221).

I tried increasing max-http-header-size, but could not get it to work on Azure. So my solution for now is to use an older version of node. Hoping there will be a solution posted in those discussions eventually.

Answer (score 1):

just add the --max-http-header-size in the iisnode.yml, as for the details of passing Flag to NodeJS's chrome V8 in Azure Appservice: [Pass flags to NodeJS's Chrome V8 engine in Azure Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455380/pass-flags-to-nodejss-chrome-v8-engine-in-azure-web-apps/37463977#37463977)